# CocoaPods 3rd party lib referencing main project issue

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoapods

I want my 3rd party view controller to extend my own BaseViewController for reuse, but that will make the pod project depend on the main project, which is not good. And I need to modify my pod project's header search paths in build settings each time I do a "pod install" , which is not convenient, especially for team cooperation. Another way is to modify my 3rd party view controller directly, and that leads to repeated codes. So what's the best practice in this situation?

Comment: If you're modifying the code you get from cocoapods, aren't you better off not obtaining it via cocoapods, lest you accidentally overwrite your changes with a new pod update or install?

Comment: that's right. So cocoapods is more suitable for libs that u use without doing any customization. I'll try that, thanks.